# Pick A User Who Liked My Page (Facebook)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Through Facebook's API, How do I  randomly pick a user from the list of users who liked my page for a contest? I want my program to pick it, not me randomly scroll through pages of the users on FB.

In addition, if I want to give something to say the 500th person to like the page, how can I do that?

I've been unable to find my answer in their documentation. Thanks!

Edit: I've seen answers here and elsewhere that say it can't be done. Yet companies run promotions like this all the time. What are they doing to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's against policy to run a competition on a page using Facebook native functionality (such as likes or wall posts) and there's no API to get the list of Likers back.

The workaround, and this is what most pages (and definitely almost all large brands) do is have a custom app installed on a tab and have the app on that tab accept and process the competition entries - in that case all the entries are in your own database and you can just choose one at random

Answer (score 1):

Facebook API won't tell you who likes a page so this won't be possible.

Comment: How do all these companies do it then?